# What is the value of P{X=Y<Z}

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let the Joint PDF of $(X, Y, Z)$ be $\exp(-x -y -z)$ for $x>0, y>0, z>0, 0$ otherwise.
Then, find the value of $P(X = Y < Z)$

My Approach:

1. In the PDF, set $X = Y$. This will give new PDF $\exp(-2x -z)$
2. Then integrate the PDF under two variables $x$ and $z$ with $x\in (0, z)$ and $z\in (0, \infty)$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{z} e^{-2x -z} dx dz$$

By this approach, I'm getting a value of 1/3 as the solution. However, the suggested answer is 0.
I'm not able to figure out what is wrong with my approach.

Thanks

Comment: $P[X=Y<Z]\leq P[X=Y]=0$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v's with a continuous distribution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your step 1 is wrong.  You could do the full integration $$\int_{z=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^z \int_{x=y}^y e^{-x-y-z}\,dx \,dy\,dz$$ which is clearly $0$ since  $\int_{x=y}^y e^{-x-y-z}\,dx =0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm curious why are X and Y independent? As per my understanding, (X, Y) is a multivariate random variable. Is it the case that each "component" of a multivariate RV is independent of the other?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. I'll take care from now on...

Comment: The joint pdf of $X,Y$ is $e^{-x}e^{-y}$ (for $x, y >0$). Since this is a product of  a function of $x$ and a function of $y$ it follows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy One more doubt. Why is it that P[X=Y] = 0? I understand that X and Y are independent RV with continuous distribution (and therefore S = X-Y will also have a continuous distribution. P(S = 0) = 0).  But, wouldn't it mean that two ind. cont. RV can never be equivalent? Is that the case? Please note that the marginal PDF and also the DF of both X and Y are similar.

Comment: If you integrate the joint density over $\{(x,y): x=y\}$ you get $0$ (whatever the density function is). This is because the line $x=y$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Yes, If $X=Y$ then $X$ and $Y$ cannot be independent except when they are constant r.v.'s.